# Translations are halved?

Tags: transforms, units

I just started Blender and for some reason whenever I manually enter in translation values they are half of what is actually intended. For example, normally when a translation of an edge on the Z-axis is moved .08 units (as in a video I was watching), my edges visually translate up half the distance compared to the other user.

When I double it and enter in .16, it translates up the same distance as in the video. Was wondering how I would be able to fix this or what is causing it.

Comment: Is it possible you could link to the video (and the specific time in the video)? Do you have any unit settings set in *Properties > Scene*? Does it still happen in new .blend? What about in a new .blend with factory settings (*File > Load factory settings*)?

Comment: Ah. Well, on making a new file it doesn't happen. I am just wondering why it happened in the first place. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed. If it's still happening in the first .blend, chances are it's some setting or perhaps an oddity with object scale. If you care to [upload that .blend](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/344/599), we can poke around in it and see if anything presents itself